# Writing two parts of a string in golang

Tags: go

I am just learning golang, and yesterday I created a pretty simple contact form. I just has the user put in their email address and write a simple message. This is how it gets sent in the email:

```
msg := &Message{
    Email:   r.FormValue("email"),
    Content: r.FormValue("content"),
}
```

When I get the email, all I get is the content of the message. I am looking to add a lot more fields. So in order for it not to get confusing, I want there to be something like `Message:` in front of `r.FormValue("content"),`. This would be something to make the emails more organized.

**EDIT**: I am so sorry for the confusion, I wrote this in a rush. So basically I have a golang contact form that asks for the users email address and a message. When they hit submit, I get an email that has their address in the subject, and the message in the body. Lets say they put something like: "Hey, my name is Joe, and I would like to get in touch". I would get those same exact words in the body of the email. I am looking to add more textareas, so in order for me not to get confused, it would be great if in front of the message it would say `Message:`. The whole email body would look like this:

Message: Hey, my name is Joe, and I would like to get in touch.

I am using `r.FormValue("content"),` to get the contents of the message, now I need a way to add the string `Message:` in front of it.

Please let me know if you want me to explain it better.

Comment: I re-read that few times and I still don't understand what you're trying to do, maybe add an example pseudo code (or php or any other language you're familiar with).

Comment: @OneOfOne please see my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, all you need to do is

```
msg := &Message{
    Email:   r.FormValue("email"),
    Content: "Message: " + r.FormValue("content"),
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out when I get home.